# Include header file of template type

Tags: c++, templates, header, include

I'm writing a template class, let's say

```
template <class T>
class bla {
    bla() ;
    ~bla() ;
};

template <class T>
bla<t>::bla(){}

template <class T>
b<t>::~b(){}
```

This works fine as long as T is `int`, `char`, and so on ... but in case that it will be a custom class `MyClass`, it will requiere the headerfile `MyClass.h` to be included, or am I wrong?

Question: How can this be done in a template-ish way, i.e. something like

```
#include "T.h"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `bla<MyClass>` you need to have included the definition of `bla` and the definition of `MyClass`. It isn't necessary that `MyClass` is known when `bla` is defined. The magic about this is called "two-phase name look-up": while compiling the template definition all names not depending on the template parameter are looked up. During the second phase, when the template is instantiated, all remaining names are looked up in the context of the instantiation.

Comment: So I just have to make sure, that `MyClass` provides all the methods used by the template `T` in the template class `bla` (in case that I instantiate `bla<MyClass>`?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Essentially, every template should be thought of being implemented using certain _concepts_, i.e. collections of operations and types with they respective semantics and performance complexity. The template argument then needs to _model_ this concept, i.e. provide all the required operations and types.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is the other way round. If you have a class `MyClass` that you want to use in one of your modules (translation units in C++), then you will include the template container (the source code you put above, lets name it `container.h`), and then create the data structure.

```
// main.cpp

#include "container.h"
#include "myclass.h"

int main()
{
    bla<MyClass> foo;

    // lots of more things...
}
```

Maybe the problem is that you don not know how to divide your code in modules. A simple rule of thumb is to put each class in a single module, each module with a .h file (the interface, in which all declaration lie), and the .cpp file (the implementation file, where roughly you write the inside of methods).

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, that's not my problem. The point was more what Dietmar Kühl answered. I am/was wondering, how the template class `bla` nows about the methods of `T`, i.e. `MyClass`.

Comment: Okay, I suppose I misunderstood the question. Thanks for reading and make the effort of commenting, anyway.